# Why does nested array crach excel when it reaches upper limit?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have the following code which crashes excel when run:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Calculations
    x As Double
    x2 As Double
    x3 As Double
    x4 As Double
    x5 As Double
    h1 As Double
    v1 As Double
    a1 As Double
    p1 As Double
    h2 As Double
    v2 As Double
    a2 As Double
    p2 As Double
    h3 As Double
    v3 As Double
    a3 As Double
    p3 As Double
    h4 As Double
    v4 As Double
    a4 As Double
    p4 As Double
    h5 As Double
    v5 As Double
    a5 As Double
    p5 As Double
End Type

Private Type Points
    Point() As Calculations
End Type

Private Type Sections
    Section() As Points
End Type

Function DynamicRedim()

    Dim aSections As Sections
    Dim aCalculations As Calculations
    Dim aPoints() As Points

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim aSectionsDimension As Integer
    Dim aPointsDimension As Integer

    Dim aSectionsCount As Integer
    Dim aPointsCount As Integer


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    aSectionsDimension = 1
    aPointsDimension = 5


    ReDim Preserve aSections.Section(aSectionsDimension)

    aPoints = aSections.Section()
    ReDim Preserve aPoints(aPointsDimension)

    For i = LBound(aSections.Section) To UBound(aSections.Section)
        aSections.Section(i).Point = aPoints
    Next

    For aSectionsCount = LBound(aSections.Section) To UBound(aSections.Section) '<< believe crash occurs when aSectionsCount = UBound(aSections.Section)?????
        For aPointsCount = LBound(aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point) To UBound(aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point)
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).x = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).x2 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).x3 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).x4 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).x5 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).h1 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).v1 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).a1 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).p1 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).h2 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).v2 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).a2 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).p2 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).h3 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).v3 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).a3 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).p3 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).h4 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).v4 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).a4 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).p4 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).h5 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).v5 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).a5 = 0
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Point(aPointsCount).p5 = 0
        Next
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function
```

I added the nested for loops towards the end of the function to zero all the elements in the type.  Before I added this step, I noticed the elements towards the end (ie v4,a4,p4,h4,v5,a5,p5,h5) somehow ended up with some really strange values - random numbers to power e-211.

Clearly I did not set these values but equally I don't want them either!!

This aside, the code should not crash excel either...I'm pretty certain that this occurs then the outer `for` loop reaches `UBound(aSections.Section)`.

I cannot see any reason why this would do this.  I've tried two separate computers to eliminate any computer related issues and it looks to be code related.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: It is not clear for me which one should be your expected result, anyhow, `aSections.Section(aSectionsDimension)` it is defining as a 1-dimensional array. Is it what you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Point` and `Points` are both Excel Classes.  It is always a bad idea to use the name of an Excel data type as the name of one of your variables.  However, I do not believe that is the cause of the crash.

DynamicRedim does not return a value so it is a `Sub` not a `Function`.  This is not important since you are not trying to return a value.

I believe the first problem is:

`aPoints = aSections.Section()`

Both `aPoints` and `aSections.Section()` are arrays of Points but they are defined in different ways.  I suspect the alignment is slightly different and memory is being corrupted.

I believe the same sort of memory corruption occurs with:

```
For i = LBound(aSections.Section) To UBound(aSections.Section)
  aSections.Section(i).Point = aPoints
Next
```

When I single step through your code, Excel crashes halfway down the first loop.  It is possible to obtain the address of an Excel variable so we could perform a detailed investigation and prove the problem is corrupted memory but I do not think it would be worth the time.

Your problem is that you are trying to ReDim an array by copying a predefined array to it.  I have copied arrays successfully but with the source and destination arrays having an identical definition.  You cannot ReDim an array of arrays in the conventional way but you can ReDim aSections.Section(i).Point.

I have rewritten your code so it works.  I have included an explanation for each of my changes.  Come back with questions if those explanations are not adequate.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Calculations
    x As Double
    x2 As Double
    x3 As Double
    x4 As Double
    x5 As Double
    h1 As Double
    v1 As Double
    a1 As Double
    p1 As Double
    h2 As Double
    v2 As Double
    a2 As Double
    p2 As Double
    h3 As Double
    v3 As Double
    a3 As Double
    p3 As Double
    h4 As Double
    v4 As Double
    a4 As Double
    p4 As Double
    h5 As Double
    v5 As Double
    a5 As Double
    p5 As Double
End Type

' Every use of "Point" replaced by "Pnt" to avoid any conflict
' with Excel classes Point and Points
Private Type Pnts
    Pnt() As Calculations
End Type

Private Type Sections
    Section() As Pnts
End Type
Function DynamicRedim2()

    Dim aSections As Sections
    'Dim aCalculations As Calculations    ' Not used by this code
    'Dim aPoints() As Points              ' Not used by this code

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim aSectionsDimension As Integer
    Dim aPntsDimension As Integer

    Dim aSectionsCount As Integer
    Dim aPntsCount As Integer

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    aSectionsDimension = 1
    aPntsDimension = 5

    ' Removed Preserve because nothing to preserve
    ReDim aSections.Section(aSectionsDimension)

    ' Use ReDim to size array rather than copying array of correct size
    ' Note: if "aSections.Section(i)" was an array, you cannot ReDim
    ' in this way because the syntax is invalid. You must pass
    ' "aSections.Section(i)" to a subroutine which can ReDim it.  If this
    ' in not clear, I will construct an example to show what I mean.
    For i = LBound(aSections.Section) To UBound(aSections.Section)
      ReDim aSections.Section(i).Pnt(aPntsDimension)
    Next

    ' Display aSections to show already initialised to zeros.  VBA initialises
    ' all variables to a default value.
    Call DsplSection(aSections)

    For aSectionsCount = LBound(aSections.Section) To UBound(aSections.Section)
        For aPntsCount = LBound(aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt) To _
                         UBound(aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt)
            ' I have changed the zeros to non-zero values to prove the code is
            ' changing all the elements.
            ' "1" is stored as an Integer and will have to be converted to a Double
            ' for each statement for each loop. "1#" tells the compiler to store 1
            ' as a Double.
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).x = 1#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).x2 = 2#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).x3 = 3#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).x4 = 4#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).x5 = 5#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).h1 = 6#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).v1 = 7#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).a1 = 8#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).p1 = 9#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).h2 = 10#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).v2 = 11#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).a2 = 12#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).p2 = 13#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).h3 = 14#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).v3 = 15#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).a3 = 16#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).p3 = 17#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).h4 = 18#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).v4 = 19#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).a4 = 20#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).p4 = 21#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).h5 = 22#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).v5 = 23#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).a5 = 24#
            aSections.Section(aSectionsCount).Pnt(aPntsCount).p5 = 25#
        Next
    Next

    ' Display new values
    Call DsplSection(aSections)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function
Sub DsplSection(ByRef SectionCrnt As Sections)

  ' For VBA, "Integer" specifies a 16-bit integer while "Long" defines a
  ' 32-bit integer. Integer variable are supposed to take longer to process
  ' than Long variable on 32-bit and 64-bit computers.  VBA routines are
  ' difficult to time because of all the background processing that can occur
  ' at any time. My experiments have failed to detect any difference between
  ' Integer and Long variables. However, no harm in having the bigger variable.
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim InxP As Long

  For InxS = LBound(SectionCrnt.Section) To UBound(SectionCrnt.Section)
    For InxP = LBound(SectionCrnt.Section(InxS).Pnt) To _
               UBound(SectionCrnt.Section(InxS).Pnt)
      Debug.Print InxS & " " & InxP & ": ";
      ' Note how much typing you save using a With statement
      With SectionCrnt.Section(InxS).Pnt(InxP)
        Debug.Print .x & " " & .x2 & " " & .x3 & " " & .x4 & " " & .x5 & " " & _
                    .h1 & " " & .v1 & " " & .a1 & " " & .p1 & " " & .h2 & " " & _
                    .v2 & " " & .a2 & " " & .p2 & " " & .h3 & " " & .v3 & " " & _
                    .a3 & " " & .p3 & " " & .h4 & " " & .v4 & " " & .a4 & " " & _
                    .p4 & " " & .h5 & " " & .v5 & " " & .a5 & " " & .p5
      End With
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```